# Как в Python пройти цикл, чтобы последовательно сложить перемноженные элементы?

Tags: python, циклы

Мне требуется положить в список `parameters_list` результат перебора, полученный так: сначала там должна появиться разница `(x-x_0)`, где `x` взят из списка `x_j_list`, а `x_0`- из списка `x_col_list`.

Затем в `parameters_list` должен появиться другой элемент: произведение первой разницы и второй. Ее получаем вычитанием из того же самого `x` следующего за нулевым элемента списка `x_col_list`. И так далее, пока не закончатся элементы в данном списке (их там столько, сколько составляет переменная `order`).

Принцип показан в формуле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Составил скрипт, который работает, не как ожидается. Ответы, которые получаю, не очень-то сходятся после второго (первые два алгоритм считает верно).

Мой выход: `Список parameters_list:  [0.15707963267948966, -0.024674011002723394, -0.07402203300817019, -0.12337005501361697]`.

При этом вместо элемента `-0.074` мой устный счет дает `0,011`; вместо элемента `-0.123` считаю другой: `-0.008`.

Код:

```
x_j_list = [(0.05*np.pi*j) for j in range(0, 21)]
point_elem_j = 1
order = 4
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3141592653589793, 0.6283185307179586, 0.9424777960769379]

parameters_list = []
for args, elems in enumerate(x_col_list):

    poly_0 = x_j_list[point_elem_j] - x_col_list[0]
    print(x_col_list[0])
    print('poly_0: ', poly_0)
    print('elems: ', elems)
    if not args:
        parameters_list.append(poly_0)
    
    if args in range(1, order):  # args = 1,2
        poly_n =  (x_j_list[point_elem_j] - x_col_list[args])*poly_0
        print('elems: ', elems)
        print('poly_n: ', poly_n)
        if args:
            parameters_list.append(poly_n)
        poly_0 = poly_n
        
print('Длина parameters_list: ', len(parameters_list))
print('Список parameters_list: ', parameters_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если следовать этой логике, то можно сделать так:

```
x_j_list = [(0.05 * np.pi * j) for j in range(0, 21)]
point_elem_j,order = 1,4
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3141592653589793, 0.6283185307179586, 0.9424777960769379]

poly_n = x_j_list[point_elem_j] - x_col_list[0] # считаем первый элемент
parameters_list = [poly_n]  # помещаем первый элемент в итоговый список
for args, elems in enumerate(x_col_list[1:]): # итерируемся по списку, начиная со второго элемента (индекс == 1)
    poly_n = (x_j_list[point_elem_j] - elems) * poly_n # считаем второй и последующие элементы
    parameters_list.append(poly_n) # и помещаем их в список

print('Длина parameters_list: ', len(parameters_list))
print('Список parameters_list: ', parameters_list)
```

```
Длина parameters_list:  4
Список parameters_list:  [0.15707963267948966, -0.024674011002723394, 0.011627353755112431, -0.009132102284437726]
```

Разница в расчетах у вас возникала в связи с тем, что на каждой итерации цикла значение `poly_0` сбрасывалось на первоначальное, т.е. операция `poly_0 = poly_n` была вхолостую. Если бы вы вынесли `poly_0 = x_j_list[point_elem_j] - x_col_list[0]` до начала цикла, результат был бы правильным. Этим также объясняется корректность первых двух элементов - они  рассчитываются и заносятся в список до операции `poly_0 = poly_n`.